# Summing Stream of Elements until Desired Value

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

`count` takes `Stream[Int]` and `desiredNum` arguments. It adds the head of the stream (in a, I believe, lazy fashion) until the running sum `>=` the `desiredNum`.

Example: `count(Stream.continually(1), 2)` should get output of 2 since `1 + 1 = 2`.

Here's my code:

```
  def count(as: Stream[Int], desiredNum: Int): Option[Int] = {
      def go(bs: Stream[Int], currentNum: Int, count: Int): Option[Int] = 
       bs match {
        case x #:: xs if(currentNum >= desiredNum) => Some(count)
        case x #:: xs => go(xs, currentNum + x, count + 1)
        case Stream() => None           
      }
      go(as, 0, 0)
   }
```

Tests:

```
scala> count(Stream(1), 1)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> count(Stream.continually(1), 100)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(100)
```

**EDIT** Note that I changed my question after seeing that I was not checking the right value in my first `case` statement. Initially I was using `x` (head of Stream) rather than `currentNum`. This led to an infinite loop.

But, is there a particular limit on `desiredNum` with respect to CPU and RAM? Is this function **correctly** using `Stream`'s? (Perhaps there's a poor usage of RAM in `count`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question reduces to "is `count` tail recursive". And it is. So no references to intermediate stream values (`x`) or computations (`currentNum + 1`) need be retained. Scala has the `@tailrec` annotation which lets the compiler verify that your recursion is in the tail position and thus is able to perform the tail call optimization.

Comment: Additionally, I was curious if my `count` function could be more concise. [I need to remember to use `@tailrec` - I usually forget]